# How can I render data from multiple columns into one column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to render the values from two different columns into my jquery datatable

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

$(document).ready(function(){

    var table = $('#table').DataTable({

         "ajax": {
                "url": "data.json",
                "dataSrc": "",
            },

         "columnDefs": [
            {
               "render": function (data, type, row) {
                   var result = 'The id is ' + data[0] + ' and the name is ' + data[1];
                        return result;
                    },
                    "targets": 0,
                },      

         ],

        "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "id"
                },
                {
                    "data": "name"
                }
            ]
    });

});
```

data.json:

```
[{
    "id": "12",
    "name": "Laura"
}]
```

But my result is:

```
The id is 12 and the name is undefined
```

Comment: It should be `row[0]` not `data[0]`.

Comment: @markpsmith But then my result is: The id is undefined and the name is undefined

Comment: it should be `var result = 'The id is ' + row["id"] + ' and the name is ' + row["name"];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please change the following:

```
"columnDefs": [
            {
               "render": function (data, type, row) {
                   var result = 'The id is ' + row["id"] + ' and the name is ' + row["name"];
                   console.log(result);
                        return result;
                    },
                    "targets": 0,
                },      

         ]
```

Use `row["id"]` instead of `data[0]`;